# Chart.js v2 FillColor Vs BackgroundColor

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to draw a  line chart with using Chart.js version 2, as i undrestood in this version we dont have 
fillColor property anymore and instead of it we should use backgroundColor,
I have 2 different datasets and i want to fill them with different color also i want to set opacity to 0.

```
     datasets: [ {
                    label: "This Year",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(225, 236, 240, 1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(107,200,213,1)",
                    data: [1200,800,300,460,500]
                },
                {
                    label: "Next Year",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(83,132,153,1)",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(184, 0, 36, 1)",
                    data: [200,500,1300,610,320]
                 }
        ]};
```

the issue that i've faced is some parts of   "Next Year" 's wave and it's data points will be hide behind "This Year" wave.
with fillColor in the previuse version we dont have this issue i guess, 
could you please guid me how can i solve this problem? ......

Comment: Setting the opacity to 0, or setting the `fill`property to `false` will give you [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SujkO.png), where you can see both datasets. Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you Tektiv, but actually i want to have background color for each wave, so the fill propery should set true and I want to set Alpha in rgba(225, 236, 240, 1) to 1, then i will miss data points

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how it works. I haven't worked with Chart.js **v1** so I don't know your `fillColor` property .. But in **v2**, graphs are drawn (lines and background) after each other so you had to expect the result you have with this code. Unless you lower a bit the opacity (= alpha) of your color, I don't think you can expect something else. -- You could also edit the [source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/src/) but it is quite tough and boring for what you are looking for.